# Convert JSON with integers to Java POJO objects

Tags: java, json, pojo

I have this JSON data, and I was wondering how I might convert this data to a Java POJO object:

```
"progression": {
    "64693": [
        {
            "1": 1
        }
    ],
    "64717": [
        {
            "1": 4
        }
    ]
},
```

I was thinking it can't be:

```
public class Progression{
private List<64693> 64693;
private List<64717> 64717;

public List<64693> get64693(){
    return this.64693;
}
public void set64693(List<64693> 64693){
    this.64693 = 64693;
}
public List<64717> get64717(){
    return this.64717;
}
public void set64717(List<64717> 64717){
    this.64717 = 64717;
}
}
```

I'm very familiar with Java, so I know I can do a @JsonProperty instead of the actual numbers, but just wondering if there were any other choices.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't name fields starting with a number in Java. Maybe try putting them into a `Map<Integer,Integer>`?

Comment: Take a look at [`gson`](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Comment: You can also map it to a generic `JSONArray` object, most libraries have an implementation. Think Node or Element for a XML document but for json. Also if you want it in the `Progression` object consider naming `64693` to like `DataType64693` and adding the `@JsonProperty("64693")` annotation. If you have a specific library your using I would be happy to provide the implementation.

Comment: One poster already suggested `gson`. Other Options include `FlexJSON` and `Jackson`. Really, with any of these libraries conversion into a simple Map object is the starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

_ug had the right suggestion:

> ... object consider naming 64693 to like DataType64693 and adding the
>   @JsonProperty("64693") annotation

That worked fine.   And BTW, I am using the Jackson 2.0 JSON processor.